# Restricting a search in Xcode to lines changed since the last commit

Tags: ios, xcode, git

In Xcode 10, I want to search for certain strings but only match lines that have been changed since the last commit.  For example, I often add a "TODO" comment in places that I plan to review later.  I want to find the TODOs that I've added since the last commit, ignoring the many older TODOs that were there prior to the commit.  (I'm using the Source Control built into Xcode.)

I can show differences since the last commit and scroll through for the TODOs, but I'm overwhelmed by dozens of source files and many other edits.

One solution might be to use a spelling variation.  For example, type lower case "todo" and then, immediately before a commit, do a mass search and replace to change all lower case "todo"s to upper case.  A case-sensitive search for "todo" would show me the recent lines.  Or, I could also use a different word entirely, and later replace them with TODO.  Both ideas require a change in workflow habits.

Can I restrict a string search in Xcode to the lines that were changed since the most-recent commit?